# Why isn't the mini-panel I've created appearing as a panel I can add?

Tags: 7, panels

I've made a mini-panel and placed it in a category. Now I want to add my mini-panel to a panel page. Only, when I go to add the component I don't see my mini-panel anywhere.

I tried changing it to a different category, refreshed cache and rebuilt registry but theres no change.

Would anyone know what I could do?

(this is in Drupal 7)

Comment: I would check the context of both the mini panel and panel. Let's say if the context of _node_ is added to a mini panel, you are only able to add the mini panel to a panel which has _node_ as a context (arguments).

Comment: Is this using Panelizer?